# Comparing Two Images / Matching a Complex Gesture

Tags: image, algorithm, language-agnostic, logic, gesture-recognition

Can anyone give some advice to the thought process of matching complex patterns. For example, if I show the user a treble-clef and they draw the pattern.

I need to generate a number representing how close the line was to the source. For my example, i want to ignore speed, pauses, or other time based elements just the final product.

I have been racking my brain and 'google'ing but have not seen any example that helps.

Comment: It might be helpful if you share what type of drawing device you intend to use.

Comment: In this case the "original" and the "copy" will be an ordered set of lines with start and end plots

Comment: Would there be a difference in score if the long, vertical line of the treble clef were drawn first or last? Or if the two dots for the bass clef were drawn first or last? My thinking is that if there is no differnce, then you are doing more character recognition and less gesture recognition.

Comment: In the context of my application, yes the order of the shapes are important

Comment: These nuggets from the Consumer Electronics Show might give you a start. http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/technology/2012/01/40031/ or http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/article/412048/audi_shows_gesture-driven_three-panel_heads-up_dashboard_display/.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for "Computer Vision Gesture Recognition" and found a student [review paper](http://students.sabanciuniv.edu/~kamer/Magitact/References/Other%20Papers/Vision_Gesture_Recog.pdf) that surveys the field and may give you some helpful references.